# Struts2 taglib, compare with null

Tags: struts2, taglib, ognl

I am trying to know why this code is not working when I compare a String with null in a JSP.

```
<s:set name="myvar" value="%{'teststring' != null}" /> <!-- always true -->
myvar value is ${myvar}
```

Above code works fine, and prints "`myvar value is true`".

But doing any of these

```
<s:property value="myvar" />
<s:property value="%{myvar}" />
```

throws a ClassCastException

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

So I do not know how to solve it, as I need to disable some inputs based on that variable value, ie.

```
<s:select ... disabled="%{myvar}" />
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:
`<s:property value="%{#myvar}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<s:property value="%{myvar.toString}" />
<s:select ... disabled="%{myvar.toString}" />
```